# Matrix expression

Tags: matrices

The products $P$ and $Q$ are to be processed using two machines, $A$ and $B$. Each unit of $P$ requires $6$ hours in machine $A$ and $2$ hours in machine $B$ while each unit of $Q$ requires $5$ hours $A$ and $3$ hours in $B$. If the number of hours available in $A$ and in $B$, are $36$ hours and $18$ hours respectively. Express the following information in matrix form.

Answer (score 0):

You actually wish to find out how many of $P$ and $Q$ should be produced by machines $A$ and $B$ respectively. Assuming that the machine produces the whole product or none of it, let's say machine $A$ produces $h$ units of $P$ and $k$ units of $Q$; Also, machine B produces $u$ units of $P$ and $v$ units of $Q$. You can form 2 equations here:

$$
6h + 2k = 36\\
5u + 3v = 18
$$

Unfortunately, your information only takes it this far and it is hard to create matrix form.

Comment: unfortunately its an assignment question and it came like it is. thanks for attempting it

Comment: You should re-read the question. I have this slight feeling you are asked to solve a pair of simultaneous linear equations. If that happens then you can arrange it into a matrix form. Else, this is the best we can go.